# playing .mp4 video using flowplayer on bootstrap 3 model in firefox - cannot load the screen

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I have done a enough RnD in solving this issue in firefox.
Trying to load the .mp4 video using flowplayer on bootstrap3 model,
Screen doesnt get loaded but i could hear the audio.
is it issue related with flowplayer?? or the css??
Im trying to include the player in the 'a' tag

```
var data = flowplayer("videoFrame", base_url + "/js/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    // this will enable pseudostreaming support
    plugins: {
        pseudo: {
            url: base_url + "/js/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf"
        }
    },
    // clip properties
    clip: {
        // our clip uses pseudostreaming
        provider: 'pseudo',
        url: 'http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4'
    }

});
```